# add items to an already existing combobox cell in a datagridview comboBox column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010

How can I add items to an already existing combobox cell in a datagridview combobox column. ProductGrid is dataGridView.

```
       With ProductGrid
         Dim objSerialNumber As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        With objSerialNumber
            .Name = "SerialNumber"
            .HeaderText = "SerialNumber"
            .Visible = False
            .Width = lGridWidth * 1.2
        End With
        .Columns.Add(objSerialNumber)
       End With
```

There is another function where i have to add items in SerialNumber comboBox. And item that i have to add is in array. And which line of code will be used to remove items from comboBox if already added in ComboBox column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem stated above in this manner. gSerialNumberArray contains items that i have to add.

```
 Dim cbCell As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell

    For k = 0 To ProductGrid.Rows.Count - 1
        cbCell = ProductGrid.Rows(k).Cells("SerialNumber")
        For iIndex = 0 To UBound(gSerialNumberArray)
            cbCell.Items.Add(gSerialNumberArray(iIndex))  
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Yes I agree, strangely `.AddRange(gSerialNumberArray)` did not work for me causing the control to fire runtime errors, so I had to use a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Normally combobox add item Command is applicable instead of using your DatagridviewCombobox Cell Name

```
dgvcomb.Items.Add("30")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Column4.Items.Add(tds1.Tables(0).Rows(ij).Item(0))

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

cbCell.Items.AddRange(strArray)

If you already loaded the items into an array, this loads them all in the pulldown.  If you are collecting them from say a database table, use the arraylist function to load the database items into the list, then convert the array list to an array.